# Consume wcf service from asp.net core Credentials not found

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, wcf

I have added a service reference with Visual Studio WCF connected service.

When I try to consume I receive the exception that the credentials are not found.

I´ve been able to consume this service in ASP.NET MVC but to make this work I made a trick to overriding the headers in the request:

```
public class AgendasWs2 : CatalogosAgendasWS_A
{
    protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request;
        request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);

        if (PreAuthenticate)
        {
            NetworkCredential networkCredentials = Credentials.GetCredential(uri, "Basic");
            if (networkCredentials != null)
            {

                byte[] credentialBuffer = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(networkCredentials.UserName + ":" + networkCredentials.Password);

                request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(credentialBuffer);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("No network credentials");
            }
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

As you can see I override the headers before sending the request.

The service has a Preemptive authentication type

How can this be done in ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

```
 CredentialCache myCredentialCache = new CredentialCache();
 myCredentialCache.Add(new Uri(url),"Basic", new NetworkCredential(userName,password,domainName));
 NetworkCredential myCredential = myCredentialCache.GetCredential(new Uri(url),"Basic");
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy4394xd(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)